# Variable coming back undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope

My return variable keeps coming back undefined. Can someone please explain why? as far as I can tell it should be in scope.

```js
var countBs = function(word) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    if (word.charAt[i] == 'B'){
      count += 1;
      return count;
    };
  };
};

console.log(countBs('BBABBAB'))
```

Comment: `word.charAt` is a function. When you develop - ensure you understand every expression in your code and that you have checked that every expression returns exactly what you expect - using a debugger or at least a `console.log`

Comment: @Luca Explain why? Maybe he doesn't want to iterate if a value is found?

Comment: Thank you! I just figure it out. Man what a Duh moment.

Comment: `word.charAt(i)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `count` at the end of the function, and use `.charAt(i)`:

```
var countBs = function (word) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    if (word.charAt(i) == 'B'){
      count += 1;
    };
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem. but i'm still curious to know why the original code snippet returns `undefined`. I would expect it to return `1`

Comment: `word.charAt[i]` is always undefined, so the `if` is never true.

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice charAt was being used as an array. my bad